# Why is void() legal whereas void{} is not?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20

While working on a template this evening I came across something surprising. The template in question made use of `std::invoke` to call a function when a certain set of conditions are met otherwise the default constructed return type is returned after logging an error message. This was working well until I needed to apply the template to a function returning `void`. After speaking with someone more knowledgeable than myself, he pointed out that using parenthesis rather than braces for constructing the return type would be compatible with void.

Sure enough, this works with any compiler I've been able to throw at it but it bothers me on a deeper level. In the code below `R()` gives the appearance of being default constructed, but I suspect this is really a deviant case of a function-style conversion (eg. `void()`), which explains why using `R{}` (eg. `void{}`) is considered illegal by most (but not all) compilers.

Are there any language lawyers around who can verify the above and or provide advice on the most idiomatic way to implement the following template without creating two versions using concepts? (I'm currently targeting C++20).

```cpp
template<typename F, typename... Args,
         typename R = std::invoke_result_t<F, Args...>>
auto call(F&& f, Args&&... args)
{
    if (some_runtime_condition) [[unlikely]] {
        // log an error message
        return R(); // R{} is invalid for functions returning void
    }

    return std::invoke(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(args...));
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/fos4T6Wfj

TIA!

Comment: My thunder stolen, but here's a simpler example: https://godbolt.org/z/Mr7Eqq885

Comment: Returning `R()` or `R{}` seems bad.  If I have a `struct foo{int x;}` that just returned nonsense. I would take a fallback function object `auto fallback` or something that takes a `T` type somehow.  With the default fallback being 0 for floats/integers, nullopt for optional, empty for std containrrs, void for void, and an adl lookup for other types that hits a deleted function if you fail to write an overload.  But maybe I am nuts.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont In that case `R{}` would zero initialize the object since it is an aggregate.

Comment: Both `R()` and `R{}` will zero initialize aggregates.

Comment: @PaulGroke Oh yeah, the fixed that as well.

Comment: @NathanOliver was it ever broken? At least in expressions like `new T()`, I think it used to be that way as long as I can remember (C++03).

Comment: @PaulGroke I was thinking about a different feature where `T(params)` now works for aggregates.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So there are two things going on here at the same time.  First, prior to C++20 there was a defect in the standard where only the expression `void()` was allowed, this was a carry over from C++03 and was never updated in C++11 through C++17 to also allow `void{}` to do the same thing.

Since C++20 the wording of the standard is [[expr.type.conv]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.type.conv#2):

> If the initializer is a parenthesized single expression, the type conversion expression is equivalent to the corresponding cast expression. **Otherwise, if the type is cv void and the initializer is () or {} (after pack expansion, if any), the expression is a prvalue of type void that performs no initialization**. Otherwise, the expression is a prvalue of the specified type whose result object is direct-initialized with the initializer. If the initializer is a parenthesized optional expression-list, the specified type shall not be an array type.

<sup>emphasis mine</sup>

And that means your code should compile, and indeed it does compile with [GCC and MSVC, just not clang](https://godbolt.org/z/ssnj7ndcr)

Comment: Unfortunately Clang is one of the compilers I'm supporting. Reading the above, this looks like a bug in Clang - is that correct?

Comment: @StevenStallion Yes, it is a bug in clang to reject the code in C++20 mode or higher.

Comment: I liked `void()` because it reminded me that `void` is not an aggregate.

Comment: @alfC aggregates can be initialized with parentheses in C++20 too.